# App without splash screen Xcode 5

Tags: ios, splash-screen

When I don't have any splash image, I'm getting a black screen. Is it possible to have an App without splash screen?

Comment: Note that some apps use a screenshot of their app as the splash.  That's effectively no splash and gives an illusion of instant startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO** this isn't possible you are required to have a Splashscreen (Launch Image). This is a requirement by [Apple Human User Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)

Going against these guidelines will get your app **REJECTED** from the Apple App Store Review process - it will be rejected under

> **10.1** Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the [Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

You *have* to have a splash image when your application initialises.

In your case you can definitely go ahead without putting any splash screen into the app, as you are not going through Apple's review. But Apple **mandates** this for a valid reason. Its all about user experience if not branding. A black screen is like a dingy reception of a hotel which makes the guests dreadful from the very point of arrival.

It is **required** to use a splash image to get through Apple's review. In case you don't have one which shows your brand name, Apple suggests that you put something very much similar to your app's first screen with no data there.

> Design a launch image that is identical to the first screen of the
> app, except for:
>
> - Text. The launch image is static, so any text you display in it won’t be localized.
> - UI elements that might change. If you include elements that might look different when the app finishes launching, users can experience
>   an unpleasant flash between the launch image and the first app screen.
>
> If you think that following these guidelines will result in a plain,
> boring launch image, you’re right. Remember, the launch image doesn’t
> provide you with an opportunity for artistic expression. It’s solely
> intended to enhance the user’s perception of your app as quick to
> launch and immediately ready for use. For example, Settings and
> Weather each supply a launch image that is little more than a static
> background image.

Example

If you see Facebook app, they don't show "Facebook" logo as splash screen, but a screen which have a tab bar and navigation bar (actually an image of course). So, it will look to the user that the data is loading.

[image]

Comment: `" It is recommended, that you put something very much similar to your app's first screen if no data was there"` Where is this recommended????

Comment: Image is too big. Would be better to resize it =)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

Comment: I have linked to that myself and have read through it and no where does it say `"It is recommended, that you put something very much similar to your app's first screen if no data was there"` So where exactly does it state this??? I could put a random image of myself if I wanted and it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Popeye Apart from documentation that I mentioned, I remember watching a tech talk video from Apple long back where they told that if you don't want to put a splash screen at least put a screenshot of the first screen. When I say recommended, I mean it is the minimum you should do.

Comment: @Popeye yes definitely you can. But this is the bare minimum you can do. That's what I meant. The only difference is about the branding and user experience. You would also agree that using the first screen is way better than  using no image (black screen) or meaningless image.

Comment: Well if that's the case it's more then a recommendation it is a requirement, note my answer and note the Apple review process rule that it would be rejected under if you didn't include the image. The image isn't a recommendation it is a requirement. Note that nowhere in the Apple documentation that you have provided does it say **Recommend**. Please update your answer from recommend to required.

Answer (score 0):

NO, You should have to put splash screen when you upload to appStore.

> " You must provide at least one launch image. Typically, an iPhone app
>   includes at least one launch image in portrait orientation; an iPad
>   app includes at least one launch image in portrait orientation and at
>   least one launch image in landscape orientation. "

[See the Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)

Comment: Otherwise your app won't be approved.

Comment: you can't upload app for approve,

Comment: Icon image and splash screen images should be there for upload.

Comment: what if I am distributing app using enterprise license and OTA

Comment: If your distributing apps via OTA or Enterprise then they don't go through the Apple Review process and you can whatever the hell you want but you will still have that black screen if you don't provide an image.